# jersey rest: how to return interface instead of class

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I have a rest webservice. For some reason I don't want to return class which needed to be converted to interface. I want to return interface and in the JSON I want to see only the methods(which starts get) values. Not the all attributes from the implemented class.

Say for an example:

```
@Path("getValues/")
@GET   
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public DetailInterface getClientDetail() {
   return new DetailImpl(); 
}
```

and consider the interface:

```
public interface DetailInterface { 
    public String getName();
    public String getAge();
}
```

and consider the implementation

```
public class DetailImpl implements DetailInterface {
    public String getName() 
       return "my name";
    }

    public String getAge(){
       return "my age";
    }

    public String iDontWantThisinJSON() {
        return "I don't want this in JSON output";
    }
}
```

when I request the rest service I see the `iDontWantThisinJSON` attribute also comes in the JSON response. I don't want to include it in the response.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `@JsonIgnore` annotation? Marking the field as `transient` may be also helpful - however I'm not sure if it's ok.

Comment: any other option we have?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Maybe `transient` will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more of a java concept than Rest or Json. You will have to modify the code as follows and it should work as you want it to work.

```
@Path("getValues/")
    @GET   
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public DetailInterface getClientDetail() {
       DetailInterface di = new DetailImpl()
       return di; 
    }
```

Comment: No this is not working. You verified this in  your system?